# WordPress Elementor. Custom HTML not rendered

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Using Elementor to insert custom HTML code.
But it's not working. Many HTML elements are not rendered on the page at all. They seem to dissappear.

As you can see the `<form>` `<input>` and `<script>` tags are ignored

Inserted HTML:

```
<form name="landingForm" onsubmit="createObject(); return false">
    <label for="your_name">För- och efternamn</label>
    <input type="text" id="your_name" required=""><br>
    <label for="your_email">E-post</label>
    <input type="email" id="your_email" required=""><br>
    <label for="your_tel">Telefon</label>
    <input type="text" id="your_tel" required=""><br>
    <label for="your_job">Jobb-titel</label>
    <input type="text" id="your_job" required=""><br>
    <label for="your_account">Företag</label>
    <input type="text" id="your_account" required=""><br>
    <label for="agree"> Jag godkänner att mina uppgifter lagras av Chessit</label> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" value="agree" required=""><br>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Registrera">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webtracking-v01.bpmonline.com/JS/track-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://webtracking-v01.bpmonline.com/JS/create-object.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
    fields: {
        "Contact": "#your_name", // Name of a contact, registering to the event
        "Contact.MobilePhone": "#your_tel", // Contact's mobile phone
        "Contact.JobTitle": "#your_job", // Contact's job title
        "Contact.Email": "#your_email", // Contact's email
        "Contact.Account": "#your_account"
    },
    contactFields: {
        "FullName": "#your_name", // Name of a contact
        "Phone": "#your_tel", // Contact's mobile phone
        "Email": "#your_email", // Contact's email
        "Account": "#your_account"
    },
    customFields: {},
    landingId: "a52586c3-numbers",
    serviceUrl: "https://aUrl.com",
    redirectUrl: ""
};
function createObject() {
    landing.createObjectFromLanding(config);
}
function initLanding() {
    landing.initLanding(config)
}
jQuery(document).ready(initLanding)
</script>
```

Rendered HTML

```
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <label for="your_name">För- och efternamn</label>
    <br>
    <label for="your_email">E-post</label>
    <br>
    <label for="your_tel">Telefon</label>
    <br>
    <label for="your_job">Jobb-titel</label>
    <br>
    <label for="your_account">Företag</label>
    <br>
    <label for="agree"> Jag godkänner att mina uppgifter lagras av Chessit</label> 
    <br>
var config = {
    fields: {
        "Contact": "#your_name", // Name of a contact, registering to the event
        "Contact.MobilePhone": "#your_tel", // Contact's mobile phone
        "Contact.JobTitle": "#your_job", // Contact's job title
        "Contact.Email": "#your_email", // Contact's email
        "Contact.Account": "#your_account"
    },
    contactFields: {
        "FullName": "#your_name", // Name of a contact
        "Phone": "#your_tel", // Contact's mobile phone
        "Email": "#your_email", // Contact's email
        "Account": "#your_account"
    },
    customFields: {},
    landingId: "a52586c3-numbers",
    serviceUrl: "https://aUrl.com",
    redirectUrl: ""
};
function createObject() {
    landing.createObjectFromLanding(config);
}
function initLanding() {
    landing.initLanding(config)
}
jQuery(document).ready(initLanding)
        </div>
```

Why aren't my script tags rendered? It's so strange.
Is Elementor supposed to honor my custom html or is it forcing me to use WordPress-form or something else other than basic HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use html widgets for custom html so your whole code was rendered  with form, js

Comment: Should I use multiple HTML-widgets? Or what do you mean?

Comment: no, use single widgets and add whole code in widgets

Comment: My code is in one widget: https://prnt.sc/eHvmyeUPIcRo
Result is completely wrong: https://prnt.sc/i9_woqRFJfq_

Comment: browser only render from code script are rendered but no get any result from frontend side  try to inspect element so you can see that your code was rendered or not  not in editor on page

Comment: You can see the result source code in the second image. On the right side.
The HTML tags are not rendered at all by the Elementor WordPress

Comment: https://prnt.sc/o_vQFGlgNLrh check this images in my side its works